# Google Play Developer API cancelSurveyResult missing from SubscriptionPurchase.Get response

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

We are implementing server to server notifications for Android in-app purchases.

For each of the user-generated events (purchase, cancellation, etc.), we receive and parse real-time developer notifications, according to Google Play's [rtdn reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference).

After parsing each notification, we submit the subscription to the play store for verification, according to Google Play Developer API [purchases.subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions).

The JSON responses we expect back should correspond to the action that the user has taken. For example, after the SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED notification was received, the verification response looks like this:

```
{
"startTimeMillis": "1615196368232",
"expiryTimeMillis": "1615196783756",
"autoRenewing": true,
"priceCurrencyCode": "EUR",
"priceAmountMicros": "3990000",
"countryCode": "DE",
"developerPayload": "",
"paymentState": 1,
"orderId": "GPA.3391-4718-6063-47314",
"purchaseType": 0,
"acknowledgementState": 1,
"kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase"
}
```

Now, the headaches start when the user cancels their subscription (via the Play Store app), thus generating a SUBSCRIPTION_CANCELED notification. The verification response looks like this:

```
{
  "startTimeMillis": "1615196368232",
  "expiryTimeMillis": "1615196664327",
  "autoRenewing": false,
  "priceCurrencyCode": "EUR",
  "priceAmountMicros": "3990000",
  "countryCode": "DE",
  "developerPayload": "",
  "cancelReason": 0,
  "userCancellationTimeMillis": "1615196648401",
  "orderId": "GPA.3391-4718-6063-47314",
  "purchaseType": 0,
  "acknowledgementState": 1,
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase"
}
```

There are some new fields present, defining the cancellation:

```
"cancelReason": integer,
"userCancellationTimeMillis": string,
```

This is great and works as expected. **However, there are still some cancellation fields missing.** Namely, the [SubscriptionCancelSurveyResult](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions#SubscriptionCancelSurveyResult), defined as:

```
"cancelSurveyResult": {
       "cancelSurveyReason": integer,
       "userInputCancelReason": string
       }
```

The documentation mentions for both `userInputCancelReason` and `userCancellationTimeMillis`:

> *Only present if cancelReason is 0.*

`cancelReason` is already 0, as it can be seen in the screenshot attached. However, only `userCancellationTimeMillis` is present. Why is there no `cancelSurveyResult` and no `userInputCancelReason`?

> You app can look at the `cancelReason` in the subscription resource returned from the Google Play Developer API to learn why the subscription was cancelled (e.g. the customer cancelled or had billing issues). If the subscription was cancelled by the user, your app can look at the `cancelSurveyResult` field to learn why the user cancelled the subscription.

Source: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#cancel

Comment: I saw that in the response the purchaseType was 0 which meant it's from a license testing account. Did you see any survey when testing the cancellation flow? My guess is: 1) Play doesn't show any survey to testing accounts, or 2) Play doesn't show this field in case the user declined to answer the survey.

Comment: @Hanrui thanks for your inquiry! 

1) The survey is being displayed for testing accounts. 
2) I have tried picking multiple answers in the survey, in order to test this Hypothesis. No luck either :(

Comment: Hi @appoll, I believe the guide has an error on interpreting "userInputCancelReason" field, this field should only be present if cancelSurveyReason is 0, and the "cancelSurveyResult" should present if cancelReason is 0. But it did help your question here. I highly encourage you to raise your question to Play Developer support to get the accurate explanation. Best Regards!